# Unleash Process in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is is possible to 'unleash', or whatever, a process in Eclipse that you've been debugging, or simply started with 'run'? Would be nice. After such an 'unleash-ment', the unleashed process should not die when Eclipse is shut down, and should be removed from the debug view, to avoid  accidentally killing it. Essentially, become a regular application process. 
thanks, -j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such command/option in Eclipse and it might not even possible depending on the OS. If you want a Java process to survive the end of Eclipse, you must start it outside.

It's sad that, after more than a decade, creating standalone processes in Java is still so painful. There is the `-jar` option but there is no way to have more than a single `main()` method this way, few people know how to build a working classpath when starting your app this way.

Comment: I see, thanks. ISTR that in some unusual circumstances, perhaps it was Eclipse crashing, or the debug connection getting corrupted, that the child process actually became independent. Not the regular kind of useful feature though.